# How do I set the max_filename error message when using Codeigniter's file uploading class?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, error-handling

I am using CodeIgniter's File Uploading Class to upload PDF files.

I am setting the preferences as [described in the user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
$config['max_size'] = '1000';
$config['max_filename'] = 20;
```

When I try to upload a file that is of the wrong type (or too large) the corresponding error message is displayed (e.g. "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.") These error messages are stored in the `upload_lang.php` file (`./system/language/english/upload_lang.php`).

However, when I try to upload a file whose file name exceeds the length of 20 characters no error message is displayed (and non is stored in the `upload_lang.php` file).

**Question**: Where can I find (or set) this message and how can I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filename of the file being uploaded exceeds the limit set in your config, then an error won't be thrown, the filename will be truncated. This can been seen in: `system/libraries/Upload.php`:

```
// Truncate the file name if it's too long
if ($this->max_filename > 0)
{
    $this->file_name = $this->limit_filename_length($this->file_name, $this->max_filename);
}
```

This is why you can't find an error message - it doesn't exist! If you look in the same file, at the `do_upload` function you can see which errors can be generated. If you'd like to change the functionality, to throw an error if the filename size is exceeded, rather than truncate the filename, then you can [extend the upload library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

If you want to change any of the error messages or add your own, you can setup the following directories (assuming the language you're using is English):

```
application/language/english
```

Then copy the language files from:

```
system/language/english
```

CodeIgniter will then use the language files in `application` instead of `system`, [which you can modify](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html).